# Debian 9.8.0 LiveCD password?

Tags: debian, password

This might seem like a very simple question that i should be able to google out in few seconds, but exact opposite is right.

I booted liveCD of debian 9.8.0 into GUI and it asks me for password. I tried everything - blank, user/live, root/toor, live/live but nothing works and iam unable to google simple and exact answer.

I find it extremly unecessary to have password in live distor and if i would expect very easy find of it in doc - but i cant.

Please let me know if you know :]

Edit: When i check console, the system is hang on

```
debian login: user (automatic login)
Authentication failure
```

repeated several times

Answer (score 0):

On Debian Live 9.2.0 (XFCE) its username: user, password: live

Maybe an active capslock key?

Answer (score 0):

Another reboot for some reason worked normally - automatic login worked as expected, not sure why it hand first time :/